# Beacon library - bootstrapNotifier: no callback if already in a region

Tags: android, ibeacon, bootstrapping, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I'm writing a simple beacon application in Android

If started outside a region it works (here's my custom log):

```
onCreate - In
onCreate - Out
onBeaconServiceConnect - In
onBeaconServiceConnect - Out
didDetermineStateForRegion (INSIDE)
didEnterRegion - In
dER - startRangingBeaconsInRegion OK
didEnterRegion - Out
didRangeBeaconsInRegion - 1 beacons
...... omitted .....
didRangeBeaconsInRegion - 0 beacons
didDetermineStateForRegion (OUTSIDE)
didExitRegion - In
dXR - stopRangingBeaconsInRegion OK
didExitRegion - Out
didRangeBeaconsInRegion - 0 beacons
```

If started inside a region, the `bootstrapNotifier` (i.e. `monitorNotifier`) methods are not called

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

```
package it.test.test01;

import android.app.Application;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.MonitorNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier;

import java.util.Collection;


public class testApplication extends Application
    implements BootstrapNotifier, BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier {
    private final String TAG = "Application ";
    protected static final Region beaconRegion = new Region("test01", null, null, null);
    protected BeaconManager beaconManager = null;
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;

    protected static String sLog = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    logIt(TAG, "onCreate - In");
    beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
        setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));//iBeacon (tutti)
    //--- wake up the app when a beacon is seen
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, beaconRegion);
    //--- activate power saver
    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
    beaconManager.bind(this);
    logIt(TAG, "onCreate - Out");
    }

    private void logIt (String TAG, String msg) {
    sLog += TAG + msg + "\n";
    Log.w(TAG, msg);
    }

    //-------------------------//
    //--- BootstrapNotifier ---//
    //-------------------------//
    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
    String msg = "didDetermineStateForRegion ";
    switch(state) {
    case MonitorNotifier.INSIDE:
        msg +="(INSIDE)";
        break;
    case MonitorNotifier.OUTSIDE:
        msg +="(OUTSIDE)";
        break;
    default:
        msg +="(state=" +state +")";
        break;
    }
    logIt(TAG, msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
    logIt(TAG, "didEnterRegion - In");
    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
        logIt(TAG,"dER - startRangingBeaconsInRegion OK");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        logIt(TAG, "dER - startRangingBeaconsInRegion Err " +e);
    }
    logIt(TAG, "didEnterRegion - Out");
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    logIt(TAG, "didExitRegion - In");
    try {
        beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
        logIt(TAG,"dXR - stopRangingBeaconsInRegion OK");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        logIt(TAG, "dXR - stopRangingBeaconsInRegion Err " +e);
    }
    logIt(TAG, "didExitRegion - Out");
    }

    //----------------------//
    //--- BeaconConsumer ---//
    //----------------------//
    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    logIt(TAG, "onBeaconServiceConnect - In");
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
    logIt(TAG, "onBeaconServiceConnect - Out");
    }

    //---------------------//
    //--- RangeNotifier ---//
    //---------------------//

    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
    logIt(TAG, "didRangeBeaconsInRegion - " +beacons.size() +" beacons");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already inside the region when the app starts up, you will not get an entry event.  This is by design.

**EDIT: Library 2.9 has two modifications to make determining the region state at startup easier:**

1. One the app starts monitoring, the `didDetermineStateForRegion` callback is guaranteed to be called, telling you the state of the region.  (The `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` callbacks may not fire unless there is actually a change.)
2. If you want to disable region state persistence, you may do so with `beaconManager.setRegionStatePeristenceEnabled(false);`  This will guarantee a callback to `didEnterRegion` the first time a beacon is seen after app startup, even if the beacon was visible a couple of seconds prior  before app restart.

**Please do not follow the instructions below if you are on 2.9+, because the solution is deprecated, and may not work in the future.**

If you do want an extra entry event on first detection for each app startup, you can add this line of code:
    MonitoringStatus.getInstanceForApplication(this).stopStatusPreservationOnProcessDestruction();

We are working on making this behavior easier to configure in the next release.

Comment: I realized it and was back here to answer  myself: no region change = no call back.

Comment: My question now change to "how can i read region status (inside / outside) at startup?" and I'll look for the answer. Thanks for reply

Comment: Please see my updated answer which applies to a new release of the Android Beacon Library to address this issue.